# How can I get product list with its detail in rest API backend is magento2

Tags: rest, magento, magento2

I'm working on native mobile application backend is magento2 and I want to display product after customer selected a category. I am able to get list of the product by category in rest request but that list don't have much details about the product.

> Request : http://localhost/magento2/index.php/rest/V1/categories/24/products

(24 is category ID)

> Response : [{"sku":"WH01","position":1,"category_id":"24"},...]

Earlier in Magento 1.9 product list was something like

```
       {
    2: {
    entity_id: "2"
    type_id: "simple"
    sku: "Levis Bagpack"
    description: "Bagpack"
    short_description: "Bagpack"
    meta_keyword: null
    name: "Levis Bagpack"
    meta_title: null
    meta_description: null
    regular_price_with_tax: 45
    regular_price_without_tax: 45
    final_price_with_tax: 45
    final_price_without_tax: 45
    is_saleable: true
    image_url: "http://172.16.8.24:8080/magento/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg"
    }
```

What should I do to get more info about product so I can show image and other things in mobile app ?

Comment: did you manage to find the solution for it ?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try the GET `/V1/products/:sku` REST API to get all the details.

[Link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/webapi.xml#l36)

The returned value will be a representation of `\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface` (including the additional attributes)

[Link for Reference](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Api/Data/ProductInterface.php)

Check `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::get` which services the GET `/V1/products/:sku` REST API.

You can make multiple requests for all product SKUs.

OR

You can use the search API to fetch the entire list in a single request based on your criteria:

For example:

> http://localhost/magento2/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=sku&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=simple&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=sku&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=Simple2&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[current_page]=1&searchCriteria[page_size]=2

In the case of products with SKUs - simple and Simple2 are being searched.

Comment: @airboss- your reply suggest how to get details for such product but the question was how to get list of products using category id. Question was very simple but your answer is very manipulating.

Answer (score 1):

```
define('BASEURL','http://localhost/magento20_0407/');

$apiUser = 'testUser'; 
$apiPass = 'admin123';
$apiUrl = BASEURL.'index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
/*
    Magento 2 REST API Authentication
*/
$data = array("username" => $apiUser, "password" => $apiPass);                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                       
try{
    $ch = curl_init($apiUrl); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
    );       
    $token = curl_exec($ch);
    $token = json_decode($token);
    if(isset($token->message)){
        echo $token->message;
    }else{
        $key = $token;
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}


/*
    Get Product By SKU REST API Magento 2
    Use above key into header
*/
$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $key"); 
//$requestUrl = BASEURL.'index.php/rest/V1/products/24-MB01';//24-MB01 is the sku.
//$requestUrl = BASEURL.'index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[page_size]=10';// get total 10 products
//$requestUrl = BASEURL.'index.php/rest/V1/categories/24/products';// 24 category id
$requestUrl = BASEURL.'index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria=';//get all products

$ch = curl_init();
try{
    $ch = curl_init($requestUrl); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $result = json_decode($result);

    if(isset($result->message)){
        echo $result->message;
    }else{
        print_r($result);
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

Similarly you can change $requestUrl and filter product list by category id and get product detail.

Please confirm whether it solves your problem or not. Else I'll post another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, where '30' is category id. http://magentohost.com/rest/default/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&%20searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=30&%20searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this endpoint instead of your endpoint:

```
/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=24&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

It is the same as @Alexander Timonchev, But you have to remove the space after `&`